# Fill a box with colors JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown list which has name of some colors. Then I have a function that fills the box I have created. I want to relate them, that when I change the color from dropdown list, then press the draw button, the color that the box is filled changes accordingly. How can I do that ? Thanks. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function drawBox() {
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,600,400);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400" style="border:1px solid  #c3c3c3;">
</canvas>

<FORM NAME="table">
    <select>
        <option id=r value="Red">Red</option>
        <option id=g value="Green">Green</option>
        <option id=b value="Blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
    <input type=button value="Draw me a box" onClick="drawBox()">
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `onchange` event to select, like this `<select onchange="myFunction()">` and inside the function call `drawbox` along with required arguments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
function drawBox() {

    var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
    var color = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;


    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,600,400);
}
```

Notice how i get the color from the dropdownbox

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400" style="border:1px solid  #c3c3c3;">
</canvas>

<select id="ddlViewBy">
<option id=r value="Red">Red</option>
<option id=g value="Green">Green</option>
<option id=b value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
<input type=button value="Draw me a box" onClick="drawBox()">
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And what if I want to add 2 "input type=text", which represents the starting drawing coordinates(top left) of the box. How can I do that ? Thanks in advance. Sorry I can't upvote because it says I don't have enough reputation :/

Answer (score 1):

You can always change the values in the options to the appropriate RGB values so that you can just get the value in your script:

```
<select id="selectedColor">
<option id=r value="#FF0000">Red</option>
<option id=g value="#00FF00">Green</option>
<option id=b value="#0000FF">Blue</option>
</select>
```

And your script can just get the color for the fillstyle:

```
var e = document.getElementById("selectedColor");
ctx.fillStyle = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value
```

You can still use normal color words like 'Red', 'Green', and 'Blue' for the values, but using the RGB values lets you select the shades/settings you want in the way you're already used to using.

Answer (score 0):

Give the id to select tag 
change the function

```
function drawBox() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var e = document.getElementById("color_select");
    var clr = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    ctx.fillStyle = clr;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 400);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/u1kyrya4/)